# Eclipse browsing/navigating between method arguments with Tab button

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Documentation [Tips and Tricks (JDT)](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html&resultof=%22%54%69%70%73%22%20%22%74%69%70%22%20) page, specifically in **Content assist can insert argument names automatically** section says:

> You can then use the Tab key to navigate between the inserted names.

which is true (and cool):

[image: preview]

But if you change cursor's position or press <kbd>Escape</kbd> (twice), these borders from arguments will disappear (as they should) and moving through them with <kbd>Tab</kbd> will be impossible.

[image: preview2]

Is there anyway to restore this "browsing" through arguments after its gone? I guess something like pressing a combination of keyboard keys while having cursor inside an argument?

P.S: This is the best title I could find (feel free to edit if you think there is something better). Also, I could not find any question related to this online (mark as duplicate if in SO), but it is probably because I don't know how to search it right.

Comment: I see in the content assist preferences an option to enable it automatically under auto activation... is that ticked on for ya? As I dont know how your configuration for this is set, this might seem like a "dumb question" but im trying to eliminate possibilities :)

Comment: @GalAppelbaum [These are](https://prnt.sc/t6fkfv) my content assist preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not work "out-of-the-box" within eclipse when you have left the template navigation mode

Assume you have pressed `ESC` in your example - I would do following workaround:

```java
String.format(format, args)
```

mark the bracket parts as text selection, press `DEL` so you got following

```java
String.format
```

Then press `CTRL+SPACE` again and you will get

```java
String.format(format, args)
```

again and you are back in template navigation mode.

I know this is only a workaround - if this very annoying for you please don't hesitate to add an issue at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ . If you do so, please add the link to your question.

Comment: This would not work. Imaging we have like 5 parameters, and each parameter is actually a method invocation. Each method will have its own template navigation mode, and one might get confused and lose it altogether. In such a case, this proposal does not work. Actually such a case would have resulted into this question I believe.

Comment: Yes given workaround does only start again - but at least you can retry... Super chaining methods inside methods... IMHO not so maintainable and not easy to debug - so I prefer local variables. But anyway I think the best solution would be to add a dedicated ticket to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ so the eclipse JDT team could fix it inside the product.