# jump from parameter to the next parameter

Tags: java, eclipse

if i create in eclipse a new method with autocomplete, then i can hop/jump from one parameter to the next one with the tab key. If im done/leave this mode, then the tab key dont works anymore at this method.

So i want to know, how i can enter back into this special mode, that i can hop/jump with the tab key again.

```
public String test(String a, Integer b, long c, String d)
{
    return "^^";
}
```

so i want to jump from the return type String, to the parameter a, b, and d, even though I wrote the method a long time ago. So i want reenter  that special eclipse-editing-mode.

i hope that stackoverflow is the right platform asking that kind of question. If not, i would remove that question

Comment: I don't think you can enter that mode again. But there should be a refactoring called "change signature" or similar, which might do something you need. Maybe, if you rephrase your question to better express your needs, we can come up with an answer. Why do you want to enter that special mode again?

Comment: I have asked it too. (I can't mark as duplicate since there is no upvoted answer or an answer). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116482/eclipse-browsing-method-arguments-with-tab